# How to stop new fabric.io tabspawn on every Run

Tags: google-fabric

I use Fabirc.io as it really adds simplicity to project and SDK management.

The problem is now it is spawning a dashboard tab on every run, even if you leave the previous tab open.

Is there some magic to stop this?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Try quitting Fabric.app and run this command: rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac to see if that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to stop this was to delete Fabric all together and reinstall from zero. Most painful as it requires a verification of the libraries controlled by Fabric and this took half an hour. Given in this project I was working on I only have 4 included, this was exceptionally painful.